# In Highcharts, in 3D mode, is it posible to make right hand axis not pop out?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is what I want:
[image]

Here is what I have at the moment:
[image]

As you can see, this is the result when we set the yAxis `opposite` to true. But it is not very clear to see.

I'm wondering if there is a work around to acheive what I wanted. Or maybe even just a better way to display it more clearly.

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/scottszb1987/8pnk96jf/

--------------------------update---------------------------------
I'm looking for a solution that works for dynamic chart. With customizeable screen width, 3D angles, depth, chart values, axis values, as expected the y-axis labels should always be where it should be.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for this.

You need to change [yAxis.labels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels)'s and [yAxis.title](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.title)'s **x** and **y** values.

```
yAxis: {
      lineWidth: 1,
      opposite: true,
      labels: {
          x: 120,
          y: -120
      },
      title:{
          x: -80,
          y: -80
      }
    }
```

You can see my working example in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pnk96jf/1/).

**EDIT**

For dynamic positioning, your only HighCharts option is to use [yAxis.labels.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter). You can do something like:

```
formatter: function () {
    var position = this.position;
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        if (position.y < 0) {
            position.dataLabel.attr({
                y: position.plotY + 50
            });
        }
    });
    return '<span>' + Math.abs(this.position.y) + '</span>';
}
```

**OR**

Another option is to use *jQuery* and ovirride the label position in the *load callback*;

```
$.each(yourChart.series[0].data, function(i, position) {
    if(position.y > 80) {
        position.dataLabel.attr({x:20});
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Emre Bolat, This doesn't seem work for a dynamic chart. With the screen size, 3D angles, depth or any other paramter changes, I cannot find a way to generate an equation to calculate the offsets. Sorry for not mentioning it in the question, i'm updating it.

Comment: Editted my post. But you need to write chart specific functions to make the positions dynamic. I added some examples to my post. You have to edit them according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can change getLabelPosition so it will move your yAxis labels using depth of you chart.

```
(function(H) {
    Highcharts.Tick.prototype.getLabelPosition = function() {
      var pos = origGetLabelPosition.apply(this, arguments),
        method3d = this.axis.chart.is3d;
      // Do not do this if the chart is not 3D
      if (!this.axis.chart.is3d()) {
        return pos;
      }
      var newPos = Highcharts.perspective([this.axis.swapZ({
        x: pos.x,
        y: pos.y,
        z: this.axis.chart.options.chart.options3d.depth
      })], this.axis.chart, false)[0];
      newPos.x = newPos.x - (!this.axis.horiz && this.axis.opposite ? this.axis.transA : 0); //#3788
      newPos.old = pos;
      return newPos;
    };
  })(Highcharts);
```

Here you can find an example how it can work:
https://jsfiddle.net/8pnk96jf/4/